# uploadify is not uploading file

Tags: file, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, uploadify

I have problem while using uploadify.It shows complete message but files are not moved to specified folder.
Here is my code

```
<script src="../../../../jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uplodify/jquery.uploadify.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uplodify/jquery.uploadify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uplodify/uploadify.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js"></script>
```

This is my html and js

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[

  $(document).ready(function() {

$('#file_upload').uploadify({

'swf' : '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uplodify/uploadify.swf',

'uploader' : '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uplodify/uploadify.php',

'auto' : true,

'multi' : true,

'onUploadStart' : function(file) {

alert('Starting to upload ' + file.name);

},

 'onError' : function(error_array_us) {

for (myKey in error_array_us){

alert ("error_array_us["+myKey +"] = "+error_array_us[myKey]);

}

alert('The error was: ' + error_array_us);

},

'onAllComplete' : function() {



 alert('The file was saved to: ' );

}

  });
```

my  uploadify.php is like this

```
  <?php
        $targetFolder = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/assets/upload'; // 

    $verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

    if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

// Validate the file type
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
   }
```

and I have uploadify.php same as given on website.I am using codeigniter.Plesae some one help me

Comment: This could be a server configuration issue with PHP and security (not allowed to move files to specified folder etc).

Could you add the PHP to your question please and i'll help you debug it

Comment: That reminds me - Try checking if you have CHMOD'ed the folder in which you want the files to end up (I think a level of like 777 to start with)

Comment: @Pual I had edited post.Please check it out

Comment: You're testing for $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken in your PHP code, but I don't see the field in your HTML form, sure it's being sended ?